# Rational angle dividers of equilateral triangle

Tags: triangles, rational-numbers

let ΔABC be an equilateral triangle. let P be an interior point (strictly interior, not on any border) of ΔABC. let ∠PAB=a1, ∠PBC=a2, ∠PCA=a3, ∠PAC=b1, ∠PBA=b2, ∠PCB=b3. i am interested in finding all possible cases such that:

- a1, b1, a2, b2, a3, b3 are all distinct
- a1/b1, a2/b2, a3/b3 are all rational

my motivation for former condition is to exclude the angle bisector(s) which yield trivial (so uninteresting) cases.

one set of solution which is not so difficult to find is (a1, a2, a3)=(π/30, 7π/30, 4π/15). the corresponding (b1, b2, b3)=(3π/10, π/10, π/15). we can express this in a simpler form: (a1, b1, a2, b2, a3, b3)=(1, 9, 7, 3, 8, 2)π/30

the common denominator “30” can be interpreted as the “resolution”. we divide the straight angle into 30 equal portions. 1+9+7+3+8+2=30

with the help of computer programming i found 4 more sets of solution:

- (537, 19583, 11074, 9046, 19477, 643)π/60360
- (6908, 26764, 18678, 14994, 25519, 8153)π/101016
- (324, 38090, 34838, 3576, 35809, 2605)π/115242
- (4086, 39380, 29250, 14216, 36037, 7429)π/130398

it’s quite unexpected that the next set of solution after resolution=30 occurs at resolution=60360

my conjecture: there are infinitely many sets of solution. my question: is there any analytical method to generate all sets of solution, instead of solely relying on brute force of computer programming?

Comment: Wow, interesting problem! I have to say that I'm not hopeful for a "nice" solution here, as in general, ratios of angles can be messy to deal with. Some thoughts on approaches, though: your first big decision is how to describe where the point $P$ is. One tempting idea is to use Viviani's theorem ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viviani%27s_theorem ) to do this - but this moves away from angle properties very quickly. If you were looking at ratios of lengths I'd definitely suggest this. (oops, went too long in here...)

Comment: Another idea is to specify angles $\angle PAB=a_1$ and $\angle PBA=b_2$. These have to be rational multiples of $\pi$, and are clearly enough to locate point $P$. You can then get an expression for $a_3$, but the one I have is horrible. If $C'$ is the midpoint of $AB$ and we define $\phi=\angle PCM$, it's enough for $\phi$ to be a rational multiple of $\pi$. But the expression I get is $$\tan \phi = \frac{\tan a_1 - \tan b_2}{\sqrt{3} \left(\tan a_1 + \tan b_2 \right) - 2\tan a_1 \cdot \tan b_2}$$ which doesn't look great!